# Trying to scrape Dynamic data from web using Jsoup to android app,but not getting exact data

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

Below is my code. Please go to [webpage](http://www.delhisldc.org/DynamicData.aspx) that I am parsing. I want to extract "Delhi load" and "frequency". Using `substring` I get "delhi load" correctly but in case of Frequency I fail because the position of string changes sometimes. So as result I get following results:

`50.05` or `50.0<`

because sometime decimal value creates problem.

```
class parsepage  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtload);
        Log.d("test",parseddata);
        textView.setText(parseddata);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc;
        try {
            doc=  Jsoup.connect("http://www.delhisldc.org/DynamicData.aspx").get(); 

            Element element=doc.getElementById("LblLoad");
            Element element1=doc.getElementById("LblFrequency");
            Element element2=doc.getElementById("LblMaxToday");
            delhiload=element.toString().substring(95,99);
            delhifreq=element1.toString().substring(100,105);
            delhimaxload=element2.toString().substring(99,104);
            parseddata="Delhi Load:"+delhiload+System.getProperty ("line.separator")+"Frequency:"+delhifreq+System.getProperty ("line.separator")+"Max Load:"+delhimaxload;
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     //   this.publishProgress(parseddata);
        return parseddata;
    }
}
```

Comment: `please goto webpage that i am parsing` which webpage where is the link? what is the data you are getting from the webpage , have seen the html rendered in browser console?

Comment: Is this question fully answered? Then please mark the answer or post a follow up question in the comments (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text()` method provides the functionality to grab the textnodes of a html element (see: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html). Your selectors are already correct, just use `text()` instead of your substring tries.

**Adjusted Code**

```
try {
    doc=  Jsoup.connect("http://www.delhisldc.org/DynamicData.aspx").get(); 

    Element element=doc.getElementById("LblLoad");
    Element element1=doc.getElementById("LblFrequency");
    Element element2=doc.getElementById("LblMaxToday");

    delhiload = element.text();
    delhifreq = element1.text();
    delhimaxload = element2.text();

    parseddata="Delhi Load:"+delhiload+System.getProperty ("line.separator")+"Frequency:"+delhifreq+System.getProperty ("line.separator")+"Max Load:"+delhimaxload;

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output of `parseddata`**

```
Delhi Load:5271
Frequency:50.1
Max Load:5442 at 22:50:40
```